# Vaadin widgets compile

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin

I have Vaadin 6.8.6 application and  use ant to build it. Now I want to recompile my app using ant too but compiler doesn't see my widgets that i implemented in my app. So i have such ant build script. And in my project i have packages

```
com.example.vaadinresearch
   ..ServerComponent...class
--com.example.vaadinresearch.widgetset
   ..MyApp.class
   ..MyApp.gwt.xml
---com.example.vaadinresearch.widgetset.client
   VClientComponent.class



  <project name="com.example.vaadinresearch" basedir="." default="all">
        <target name="all" depends="clean, init,compile, widgetset-init, generate-widgetset, compile-widgetset, compile, war-package">
        </target>
        <target name="clean">
            <delete dir="build" />
            <delete dir="WebContent/VAADIN" />
            <delete dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/" />
            <mkdir dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/" />
        </target>
        <target name="init" depends="clean">
            <echo message="Creating two packages:" />
            <echo message="1. WAR package that can be deployed to application server or servlet container." />
            <echo message="2. JAR package which requires JRE only, includes embedded web server." />
            <property name="server.main.class" value="com.vaadin.demo.DesktopServer" />
            <property name="webserver.jar" value="WebServer/winstone-0.9.9.jar" />
            <property file="build.properties" />
            <mkdir dir="build" />
        </target>
        <target name="widgetset-init" depends="init">
            <!-- Folders -->
            <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
            <property name="lib.dir" value="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
            <property name="build.web.dir" value="build" />
            <property name="widgetset" value="com.example.vaadinresearch.widgetset.VaadinresearchWidgetset" />
            <property name="client-side-destination" value="WebContent/VAADIN/widgetsets" />
        </target>
        <!-- Generates a combined widget set from all widget    -->
        <!-- sets in the class path, including project sources. -->
        <!-- Updates the configuration if it already exists.    -->
        <target name="generate-widgetset" depends="widgetset-init" if="generate.widgetset">
            <echo>Updating ${widgetset}...</echo>
            <echo>Remember to define the widgetset in web.xml as follows.</echo>
            <echo>
                    &lt;init-param&gt;
                        &lt;param-name&gt;widgetset&lt;/param-name&gt;
                        &lt;param-value&gt;${widgetset}&lt;/param-value&gt;
                    &lt;/init-param&gt;
                </echo>
            <java classname="com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.widgetsetutils.WidgetSetBuilder" failonerror="yes" fork="yes" maxmemory="512m">
                <arg value="${widgetset}" />
                <jvmarg value="-Xss1024k" />
                <jvmarg value="-Djava.awt.headless=true" />
                <classpath>
                    <pathelement path="${src.dir}" />
                    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/gwt-user.jar" />
                    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/gwt-dev.jar" />
                    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/vaadin-6.8.6.jar" />
                    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
                        <include name="*.jar" />
                    </fileset>
                </classpath>
            </java>
        </target>

        <!-- Compiles the widget set using the GWT compiler. -->
        <target name="compile-widgetset" depends="widgetset-init, generate-widgetset">
            <echo>Compiling ${widgetset} into ${client-side-destination} directory...</echo>
            <java classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler" failonerror="yes" fork="yes" maxmemory="1000m">
                <arg value="-draftCompile" />
                <arg value="-localWorkers" />
                <arg value="2" />
                <arg value="-style" />
                <arg value="PRETTY" />
                <arg value="-war" />
                <arg value="${client-side-destination}" />
                <arg value="${widgetset}" />
                <jvmarg value="-Xss1024k" />
                <jvmarg value="-Djava.awt.headless=true" />
                <classpath>
                    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/gwt-user.jar" />
                    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/vaadin-6.8.6.jar" />
                    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/gwt-dev.jar" />
                    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
                        <include name="*.jar" />
                    </fileset>
                    <pathelement path="${src.dir}"/>
                    <pathelement path="${build.web.dir}/WEB-INF/classes" />
                </classpath>
            </java>
        </target>
        <target name="compile" depends="compile-widgetset">
            <echo message="Compiling Vaadin application sources." />
            <path id="com.example.vaadinresearch">
                <fileset dir="WebContent">
                    <include name="WEB-INF/lib/*.jar" />
                </fileset>
            </path>
            <javac srcdir="src" destdir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes" classpathref="com.example.vaadinresearch">
            </javac>
        </target>
        <!-- Creates Vaadin WAR package (requires Application Server / Servlet Container) -->
        <target name="war-package" depends="compile">
            <echo message="Creating WAR package." />
            <war warfile="build/${ant.project.name}.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
                <fileset dir="WebContent">
                    <include name="**/*" />
                    <exclude name="WEB-INF/web.xml" />
                </fileset>
            </war>
        </target>
    </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

In web.xml file you'll have to add

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
        <param-value>you.widgetset.package</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

in VaadinApplication servlet. You may also have to have a widgetset.gwt.xml file with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet" />
    <inherits name="you.widgetset.package" />
</module>
```

Comment: Thanks! But the problem was that i didn't compile classes before GWT compilation. And so it could not found any classes except classes in additional JAR. My fault(

Comment: Thx for posting how you fixed it instead of "Oh I found the problem already". Hate it when someone does that.